# Reduce similar dependency injections definitions?

Tags: c#, service-locator

The following code injects `Handler#<MyClass#>` into `IHandler<MyClass#>`. How can I use reflection to reduce the number of lines? Or is there any other way?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    // ....
    services.AddTransient<IHandler<MyClass1>, AHandler>();
    services.AddTransient<IHandler<MyClass2>, BHandler>();
    services.AddTransient<IHandler<MyClass3>, CHandler>();
    services.AddTransient<IHandler<MyClass4>, DHandler>();
    services.AddTransient<IHandler<MyClass5>, EHandler>();
    services.AddTransient<IHandler<MyClass6>, FHandler>();
    services.AddTransient<IHandler<MyClass7>, GHandler>();
    // .... more
}
```

Comment: Mmmhhh. I wonder if you could apply the Factory Pattern instead.

Comment: Why define a generic and then use something different every time? (the `Handler1<MyClass1>`). Either don't use generics there (`public class Handler1 : IHandler<MyClass1>`) or make it really generic: `public class Handler<T>: IHandler<T>` if you make it really generic you can then do something like this: `serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(IHandler<>), typeof(Handler<>));`

Comment: @Knoop, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need reflection way then try [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor)

```
services.Scan(scan => scan.FromEntryAssembly()
     .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(typeof(IHandler<>)))
     .AsSelf()
     .WithTransientLifetime());
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Does the answer still work?

Comment: You should tell me that. Did you read docs of Scrutor? does it suit you?

Comment: Yes, it is, but check and let me know